# Scala - Using inner type definitions of generic type parameters does not compile

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to define a arithmetic expression tree representation.
DataElement represents a single key-value pair.
CalcElement represents a pair of sub(Calc or Data)Element.
For CalcElement the key is a tuple of the keys from the subElements.
The value for a CalcElement is combination of the values of the subElements using its apply method.

The following code does not compile and I am struggling to figure out why it should not.

```
trait DataElement[K] {
  type KeyType = K
  def key:KeyType
  def value:Double
}

trait CalcElement[OP1<:DataElement[_], OP2<:DataElement[_]] extends DataElement[(OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType)] //FIRST ERROR
{
  def op1: OP1
  def op2: OP2

  def apply: (OP1, OP2) => Double
  def unapplyFirst: (Double, OP1) => OP2
  def unapplySecond: (Double, OP2) => OP1

  def key: (OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType) = (op1.key, op2.key) // SECOND AND THIRD ERROR
  def value: Double = apply(op1, op2)
}
```

the FIRST ERROR is

```
Error:(12, 84) illegal inheritance;
 self-type CalcElement[OP1,OP2] does not conform to DataElement[(_$1, _$2)]'s selftype DataElement[(_$1, _$2)]
trait CalcElement[OP1<:DataElement[_], OP2<:DataElement[_]] extends DataElement[(OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType)]
```

the SECOND and THIRD ERRORS are

```
Error:(21, 46) type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_$1(in type OP1)
 required: _$1(in type OP1)
  def key: (OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType) = (op1.key, op2.key)
Error:(21, 55) type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_$2(in type OP2)
 required: _$2(in type OP2)
  def key: (OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType) = (op1.key, op2.key)
```

Could use some help in understanding the compilers way of thinking here.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your example the KeyType is undefined until the type is constructed. Hence, OP1#KeyType and OP2#KeyType won't work.

Either do this:

```scala
trait CalcElement[OP1<:DataElement[Double], OP2<:DataElement[Double]] 
extends DataElement[(OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType)]
```

OR this:

```scala
trait CalcElement[X, Y, OP1<:DataElement[X], OP2<:DataElement[Y]] 
extends DataElement[(OP1#KeyType, OP2#KeyType)]
```

The thing I am not able to understand is, why do you need to pass the KeyType for constructing the DataElement? Since, the calculation can be a tree hence why can't it be like:

```
trait CalcElement[OP1<:DataElement[_], OP2<:DataElement[_]] 
extends DataElement[(OP1, OP2)]
```

?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply @Iprakashv! Well the type of the key is not known to be a Double at this point so I want to leave that a generic type param right now. The solution with X,Y works of course but I was hoping to reduce the number of generic type params needed to define CalcElement. So instead of saying "Given X,Y, DataElement[X] and DataElement[Y] the definition of CalcElement is so and so", I was hoping to say "CalcElement comes out of two DataElement and their keys in a tuple form the key for CalcElement (no matter what their individual key types are)"

Comment: DataElement[(OP1, OP2)] doesnt work because that makes the entire DataElements part of the key of the CalcElement

Comment: Scala compiler will need those types during compilation otherwise they will be resolved only at runtime, which is what we wouldn't want. Or, make them something toplevel like AnyVal.

Comment: Muchas gracias!